# GIT Cloning failing - early EOF

Tags: git, clone, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to clone my GIT repository on another computer (worked in many other computers) and I'm getting the following error very near to the completion of the process:

```
Cloning into 'folder'...
warning: templates not found /usr/local/git/share/git-core/templates
error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: What if you repeat the process. It is always possible. It looks as if the connection is broken at one point in the process. EOF is probably the result of the closing stream...

Comment: Tried more than 5 times - always same result

Answer (score 0):

This was happening due to slow wireless connection. Try with a high speed wireless / wired connection to resolve this.